# Is the return expression always computed, or can it be optimized out by the compiler?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, javac

I know that in this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {myMethod();}
private Object myMethod() {
    Object o = new Object();
    return o;
}
```

the garbage collector will destroy `o` after the execution of `myMethod` because the return value of `myMethod` is not assigned, and therefore there are no references to it. But what if the code is something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {myMethod();}
private Object myMethod() {
    int i = 5;
    return i + 10;
}
```

Will the compiler even bother processing `i + 10`, seeing as the return value is not assigned?

And if `i` was not a simple primitive, but a larger object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {myMethod();}
private Object myMethod() {
    return new LargeObject();
}
```

where `LargeObject` has an expensive constructor, will the compiler still allocate memory and call the constructor, in case it has any side effects?

This would be especially important if the return expression is complex, but has no side effects, such as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList();
    getMiddle();
}
private Object getMiddle(List list) {
    return list.get((int) list(size) / 2);
}
```

Calling this method in real life without using the return value would be fairly pointless, but it's for the sake of example.

My question is: Given these examples (object constructor, operation on primitive, method call with no side effects), can the compiler skip the return statement of a method if it sees that the value won't be assigned to anything?

I know I could come up with many tests for these problems, but I don't know if I would trust them. My understanding of code optimization and GC are fairly basic, but I think I know enough to say that the treatment of specific bits of code aren't necessarily generalizable. This is why I'm asking.

Comment: Look at the byte code (with `javap`). But I don't think the compiler can optimize away the method call, and thus the result must be popped off the return stack regardless of whether the caller uses it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The concerns in my last paragraph, coupled with the "operation on primitives" example, are partly why I asked this question. The operation on primitives could be a very expensive purely arithmetic operation, and there would still be no method call.

Comment: There would be a method call, the compiler can't determine apriori that the method has no side effects.

Comment: In the case of `int i = 5;
    return i + 10;` the compiler would probably replace that with a constant expression `return 15;`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sorry I misunderstood your comment. What I meant is that an arithmetic operation involving only local variables would obviously have no side effects, and this would be an extreme of a spectrum, to the other end of which is a large object being created only for the sake of being returned. My question was more about where, in that spectrum, the compiler starts or stops optimizing to the extent of not performing some operations.

Comment: The _compiler_ does almost no optimization.  The _runtime_ does lots of optimizations, including ones like these.

Comment: @QBrute So in that case the operation would be replace with a constant at compile time. But what if the operation is more complex? Maybe I should have written `double` instead of `int`, but arithmetic operations can be extremely complex, would that still all be done at compile-time?

Comment: @LouisWasserman - Correct.  It is the JIT compiler that does the optimization.  The JIT compiler runs at runtime ... i.e. when you run `java` (not `javac`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, lets deal with a misconception that is apparent in your question, and some of the comments.

In a HotSpot (Oracle or OpenJDK) Java platform, there are actually two compilers that have to be considered:

- The `javac` compiler translates Java source code to bytecodes.  It does minimal optimization.  In fact the only significant optimizations that it does are evaluation of compile-time-constant expressions (which is actually necessary for certain comile-time checks) and re-writing of String concatenation sequences.

  You can easily see what optimizations are done ... using `javap` ... but it is also misleading to because the heavy-duty optimization *has not been done yet*.  Basically, the `javap` output is mostly unhelpful when it comes to optimization.
- The JIT compiler does the heavy-weight optimization.  It is invoked at runtime while your program is running.

  It is not invoked immediately.  Typically your bytecodes are interpreted for the first few times that any method is called.  The JVM is gathering behavioral stats that will be used by the JIT compiler to optimize (!).

---

So, in your example, the `main` method is called once and `myMethd` is called once.  The JIT compiler won't even run, so in fact the bytecodes will be interpreted.  **But that is cool.**  It would take orders of magnitude more time for the JIT compiler to optimize than you would save by running the optimizer.

But supposing the optimizer did run ...

The JIT code compiler generally has a couple strategies:

- Within a method, it optimizes based on the information local to the method.
- When a method is called, it looks to see if the called method can be *inlined* at the call site.  After the inlining, the code can then be further optimized in its context.

So here's what is *likely* to happen.

- Then your `myMethod()` is optimized as a free standing method, the unnecessary statements will not be optimized away.   Because they won't be unnecessary in all possible contexts.
- When / if a method call to `myMethod()` is inlined (e.g. into the `main(...)` method, the optimizer will then determine that (for example) these statements

  ```
      int i = 5;
      return i + 10;
  ```

  are unnecessary *in this context*, and optimize it away.

But bear in mind that JIT compiler are evolving all of the time.  So predicting exactly what optimizations will occur, and when, is next to impossible.  And probably fruitless.

Advice:

- It is worthwhile *thinking about* whether you are doing unnecessary calculations at the "gross" level.  Choosing the correct algorithm or data structure is often critical.
- At the fine grained level, it is generally not worth it.  Let the JIT compiler deal with it.

  **UNLESS** you have clear evidence that you *need* to optimize (i.e. a benchmark that is objectively too slow), and clear evidence there is a performance bottleneck at a particular point (e.g. profiling results).

Comment: Obviously there is a lot I didn't know about javac/JIT. And the behaviour-gathering also came as a great surprise. I always viewed the compiler/interpreter process as a magical-sneaky-genie-in-the-machine, but this clears up a lot of it. Thanks for taking some of your time to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Questions like "what will the compiler do?" about Java are a little naïve. First, there are two compilers and an interpreter involved. The static compiler does some simple optimization, like *perhaps* optimizing any arithmetic expression using effectively final operands. It *certainly* compiles constants, literals, and constant expressions into bytecode literals.The real magic happens at runtime.

I see no reason why result calculation would be optimized away except if the return value is ignored. Ignoring a return value is rare and should be rarer.

At runtime much more information is available in context. For optimizations the runtime interpreter plus compiler dynamic duo can account for things like "Is this section of code even worth optimizing?" HotSpot and its ilk won't optimize away the `return new Foo();` instantiation if the caller uses the return value. But they will perhaps do it differently, maybe throw the attributes on the stack, or even in registers, circumstances permitting. So while the object exists on the logical Java heap, it could exist elsewhere on the physical JVM components.

Who knows if specific optimizations will happen? No one. But they or something like them, or something even more magical, might happen. Likely the optimizations that HotSpot performs are different from and better than what we expect or imagine, when in its wisdom it decides to take the trouble to optimize.

Oh, and at runtime HotSpot might deoptimize code it previously optimized. This is to maintain the semantics of the Java code.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't accept more than one answer, but thank you for all the helpful info.